# Can network traffic be limited by sharing large image data priory within server and clients?

Tags: database, image-processing, web-applications, db2, etl

We have a central DB server which holds images of customers, and there is major slowness when the client apps try to view customer info with the images. The major factor to the slowness is the network, since most of the clients log in with 128kbps connections 3000km away from the central server.

Images are saved as BLOBs, DB is Db2 and my app is a web application hosted in WebSphere, and the network is internal. There is no doubt that the we shouldn't have kept the images in the DB. Keeping that issue aside, is there any mechanism to solve the issue from sharing the images to a client DB? I mean, there is a central DB and well as a client DB. Are there any big data concepts related to handling this type of issue? I checked a similar solution at https://www.symmetricds.org/.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Vague question. EDIT your question  to include details such as whether the application supports thumbnails, and the *physical layout* of the BLOB (dedicated tablespaces, file system caching, inlining, RQRIOBLK settings on both server and client, and blob and image compression details). ALSO specify Db2-server platform (z/os, iseries, luw) and version.

Comment: I would also add that knowing the typical size of these BLOBs would be helpful.